# Is there a way to determine whether or not a variable is an sObject?

Tags: apex

I have a fairly dynamic method that needs to determine whether or not an `object` (passed as a argument) is an sObject or a standard variable. Is there any way to do this?

For example, I need to determine if the `value` argument (in the code below) is an sObject:

```
static sObject methodName(String fieldname, sObject override, object value)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for `instanceof`, which lets you check a variable's data type.

From the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_instanceof.htm):

> If you need to verify at runtime whether an object is actually an
>   instance of a particular class, use the instanceof keyword. The
>   instanceof keyword can only be used to verify if the target type in
>   the expression on the right of the keyword is a viable alternative for
>   the declared type of the expression on the left.

So an example would be:

```
if (value instanceof sObject){
  // do something
}
else {
 // do something else
}
```

Comment: Not that it was asked, but you can also be more specific, such as `value instanceof account` or `value instanceof custom_object__c`.